# Value Key Dictionary lookup problem with Python3 on VS CODE

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Python 3 coding. Any Value over single digit, so you want to get the key for 33 and it returns with Key doesn't exist even though it's in the Dictionary. However, the 8 comes back with the key. I also tried another person's code and it did exactly the same thing on any value over one digit. VS CODE said that it's a problem with my program (below).  Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?  If it's not my program then is there a fix for whatever is going on with VS CODE or the MSPYTHON and MSPylance extensions?  Should I delete one or both?

```
favnum = {"gabi": 8, "kristi": 33, "reva": 11, "KC": 25, "whoever": 77}


def GetKey(val):
    for key, value in favnum.items():
        if val == value:
            return key
        else:
            return "Key doesn't exist"


print(GetKey(33))
print(GetKey(8))
print(GetKey(77))
```

Comment: You are always checking only the first item

Answer (score 0):

Though you have a loop, you return the key if the value matches for the first item, otherwise you return not found, without checking any further values.

Move what you're doing in the else outside the loop

```
def GetKey(val):
    for key, value in favnum.items():
        if val == value:
            return key
    return "Key doesn't exist"
```